Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]...what
get this  error when i try to run the server
`Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

`i THINK this chunk of code is the cause of the error but i am not sure`

router.post('/create', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = new Task(req.body);
    await task.save();
    console.log('Task created successfully:', task);
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'Task created successfully', task });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating task:', error);
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

id give you more but SO wont allow it, just ask and ill provide, the entire file
`` ` ``

const express = require('express');
const Task = require('../../models/Task');
const { verifyToken } = require('../../middleware/verifyToken');

const router = express.Router();

// Create a task
router.post('/create', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = new Task(req.body);
    await task.save();
    console.log('Task created successfully:', task);
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'Task created successfully', task });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating task:', error);
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

// Update task status to verified
router.patch('/verify/:taskId', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.taskId, { status: 'verified' }, { new: true });
    if (!task) {
      console.log('Task not found with id:', req.params.taskId);
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Task not found' });
    }
    console.log('Task verified successfully:', task);
    res.send({ message: 'Task verified successfully', task });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error verifying task:', error);
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

// Dynamically update tasks (AJAX)
router.get('/list', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasks = await Task.find({ assignedChild: req.user._id }).exec();
    console.log('Tasks list retrieved successfully');
    res.send(tasks);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving tasks list:', error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;

ive been wracking my brain over this for a while now, i need help, if you dont know what the issue is but might know a way to find theissue please let me know. if you need more files, let me know, i am sure it is a simple solutionive tried everything that i cn think of, i was expecting the server to start, btw it was working yesterday then i guess i broke it and i cant get it back


const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');

console.log('Verify token middleware executed');

const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).send({ message: 'A token is required for authentication' });
    }
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error verifying token:', error);
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid Token', error: error.message });
  }
};

module.exports = verifyToken;



here is the entire verifyToken.js

The problem is most likely that the middleware verifyToken is not a function. Can you add the code for the middleware?

The verifyToken function is still a mystery. Could you provide the code, please?

sorry, i went to sleep, but i did add the verifyToken.js to the main post
